# Why is Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() and Auth.currentSession() not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am building an app in react native with an AWS backend. I am using aws cognito through amplify to manage authentication in the app.

I am trying to integrate the ability to check whether a user is already authenticated so that they don't have to manually sign in every time they open the app.

When I use Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() or Auth.currentSession() to check the user is authenticated, they return nothing.

NOTE: when use the Auth.signIn() method, the user object it returns, returns a session.

I have configured amplify to use my pre-existing cognito user pool with the following configuration.

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";

async function amplifySetup() {
  Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
      identityPoolId: 'REGION:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
      region: "REGION",
      identityPoolRegion: "REGION,
      userPoolId: "REGION_XXXXXXXX",
      userPoolWebClientId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    },
  });
}

export default amplifySetup;
```

I have then run this command at the start of the App function in my App.js file. When I sign a user in, this returns a cognito user successfully. When I use Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() or Auth.currentSession() to check the user is authenticated, they return nothing. I have no idea what to do or what avenue to take next.

Comment: Maybe that's not what's happening here, but how are you calling `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` or `Auth.currentSession()`? Are you awaiting them?

Comment: @LawrenceGil Yes i am awaiting them

Answer (score 0):

You need to share more code and details. If you have your own UI then you'll need to `await` those APIs and call them from a hook.

If you're using Amplify's auth UI elements, then they'll take care of themselves, for the most part. You just wrap `<App />` in `<Authenticator.Provider>` to provide context.

Here's an `App.tsx` example that uses the Amplify UI elements and react-router-v6. It calls `useAuthenticator` to determine whether to show the marketing screen(s) or signed-in user screens.
Other parts of the example are in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dmost714/f2df53309653b9619fa4ff0f1aad31b5).

```
import { Authenticator, View, Image, Text, Heading, useTheme, useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import AppRoutes from "./AppRoutes"
import MarketingPage from './routes/MarketingPage'
import logoSvg from './logo.svg'

function App() {
  const { route, user, signOut } = useAuthenticator(context => [context.route, context.user, context.isPending])

  const UnauthenticatedUserRoutes = () =>
    <Routes>
      {/* Wrap marketing page in a hidden authenticator to work around a bug. */}
      <Route index element={<><Authenticator className='hidden' /> <MarketingPage /></>} />
      {/* <Route index element={<MarketingPage />} /> */}
      <Route path="*" element={
        <Authenticator
          className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-screen h-screen bg-slate-50 min-w-max' />
      } />
    </Routes >

  return route === 'authenticated' ? <AppRoutes user={user} signOut={signOut} /> : <UnauthenticatedUserRoutes />
}

const AppWithRouter = () => <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>
export default AppWithRouter
```

Comment: May I know how to get the user session like accesstoken and refresh token?

Comment: The `Auth.currentCredentials()` and/or `Auth.currentSession()` APIs may have what you're looking for. https://docs.amplify.aws/react/prev/build-a-backend/auth/

Comment: I am using Amplify v6 using fetchAuthSession but it returns undefined values.